# XBMC Television Show Naming Convention

Tags: arch-linux, kodi

I use this naming convention for my television shows, and XBMC used to work with this just fine until I upgraded to the latest version. (Note: bold items are folders)

- **Television**

  - **3rd Rock From the Sun**

    - **Season 01**

      - 01 Brains and Eggs.avi
      - 02 Post Nasal Dick.avi
      - 03 Dick's First Birthday.avi

Now that I've upgraded to the latest version, it won't detect the episodes until I make sure the show name, and season number are in each file like so...

- **Television**

  - **3rd Rock From the Sun**

    - **Season 01**

      - 3rd.Rock.From.the.Sun.S01E01.Brains.and.Eggs.avi
      - 3rd.Rock.From.the.Sun.S01E02.Post.Nasal.Dick.avi
      - 3rd.Rock.From.the.Sun.S01E03.Dicks.First.Birthday.avi

I much prefer the first naming scheme, is there a way I can get XBMC to work with the old scheme again? I've reviewed the [XBMC Wiki](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Advancedsettings.xml) and tried adding the following to my `advancedsettings.xml` file, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

```
<tvshowmatching>
    <regexp>[/\._ \-]()([0-9]+)(-[0-9]+)?</regexp>
</tvshowmatching>
```

Note: Currently running version 12.3-1 of XBMC.